# How to get value from parent FormGroup?

Tags: angular

Hi I have a form and custom validator.

**form.component.ts**

```
this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
      password: ['', [FormValidationService.passwordValidator]],
      confirm: ['', [FormValidationService.confirmValidator]],
    })
```

**validator.ts**

```
static confirmValidator(confirm: FormControl) {
    const password = confirm.parent
    console.log('confirmValidator - password: ', password)
     if (confirm !== password) {
       return { 'errMsg': 'Passwords must match.' }
     }
    return null
  }
```

I need to get password value from parent FormGroup.
[image]

Comment: confirm.parent.get('password') ?

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: Try `confirm.parent.value.password`

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: How come you're seeing the FormControl on the console if `confirm.parent` is undefined? Doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @SiddAjmera confirm.parent not undefined it contain FormGroup

Comment: But then a `FormGroup` has properties like `value` and methods like `get` on them. To which you're getting an Undefined error.

Comment: @SiddAjmera confirm.parent is a FormGroup that contain controls: password: value: "text" but I can't get this value.

Comment: Did the provided answer, solve your question?

Comment: @RubenVermeulen I'm not exactly sure and will add my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access multiple controls at once, you have to create a validator on group level rather than on control level.

Validators on group level have access to all controls inside that group and are therefore suited in your use case.

A validator on a form control should only be focussing on that single control and nothing more.

[Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation)

> To evaluate both controls in a single custom validator, we should perform the validation in a common ancestor control: the FormGroup. That way, we can query the FormGroup for the child controls which will allow us to compare their values.